# what is $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {2^{n/{{\log }_2}n}}\frac{{{{({{\log }_2}n)}^4}}}{{{n^3}}}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

what is the limitation of this weird expression?
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {2^{n/{{\log }_2}n}}\frac{{{{({{\log }_2}n)}^4}}}{{{n^3}}}$$
I've worked on it for the whole night but I can't figure it out:(

Or no limitation exists at all?

Comment: Since $n\to\infty$ iff $2^n\to\infty$, try replacing $n$ by $2^n$ everywhere and simplify a little. That will make the expression easier to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Logarithms are meaningless. And the limit od $2^n/n^3$ is...

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {2^{n/{{\log }_2}n}}\frac{{{{({{\log }_2}n)}^4}}}{{{n^3}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{n/{{\log }_2}n}}{(\frac{n}{\log_2 n})^3}\cdot\log_2n=$$

$$\ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{a_n}}{(a_n)^3}\cdot \log_2n$$

where $\ a_n\to\infty$, because for $\ n\to\infty$, $\ n\gg\log_2n$, so the limit diverges